# How to FIX: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toUpperCase') | React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to capitalize the first word of the input text 'success' to 'Success' when someone click on `Convert to Upper Case Button` using a function `capitalize` in Alert.js file but getting error in console log

> 'Alert.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'toUpperCase')'

Also white blank page is coming, can someone please fix the issue?

Alert.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Alert(props) {
    
    const capitalize = (word) => {
        return word.charAt(0).word.toUpperCase() + word.slice(1); 
    }
    return (
        props.alertData && <div className={`alert alert-${props.alertData.status}`} role="alert">
           <strong>{capitalize(props.alertData.status)}</strong> {props.alertData.message}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Alert
```

UpperCase.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Alert from './Alert';

function UpperCase(props) {

    const [text,setText] = useState('');
    const [msg,setMsg] = useState('');
    
   const setTextValue = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
        setMsg('');
    }
    const buttonClickUpper = () => {
        if(text!==''){const newText = text.toUpperCase();
            
            setText(newText);
            showAlert('Converted to Upper Text','success');
        }
            else{
                setMsg(`This field can't be`);
            } 
    }

    const buttonClickLower = () => {
        if(text!==''){const newText = text.toLowerCase();
            
            setText(newText);
            showAlert('Converted to Lower Text','success');
        }
            else{
                setMsg(`This field can't be`);
            } 
    }

    const buttonClearText = () => {
        setText('');
        showAlert('Text box cleared','success');
    }
    
    const [alertMsg, setAlert] = useState(null);

    const showAlert = (message,status) => {
        
        setAlert({
            message:message,
            status:status
        });
    }



  return (
      <>
    <div className="mb-3 my-3 container" style={props.h1style}>
                    <Alert alertData={alertMsg}></Alert>
                    <h1>Enter Text Below</h1>
                    <textarea className="form-control" onChange={setTextValue} value={text} rows="8" style={props.textAreaStyle}></textarea>
                    <div className='message' style={{color:'red'}}>{msg}</div>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary my-3 mx-2' onClick={buttonClickUpper}>Covert To Upper Case</button>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary my-3 mx-2' onClick={buttonClickLower}>Covert To Lower Case</button>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary my-3 mx-2' onClick={buttonClearText}>Clear Text</button>
                </div>
                <div className='container'>
                    <p style={props.pstyle}>{text.split(" ").length} Words and {text.length} Texts</p>
                    <p style={props.pstyle}>{0.008 * text.split(" ").length} Minutes to Read</p>
                </div>
                <div className='container'>
                    <h2 style={props.h1style}>Preview</h2>
                    <p style={props.pstyle}>{text}</p>
                </div>
                </>
  )
}

export default UpperCase
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself,

Changed this:

```
return word.charAt(0).word.toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
```

To this:

```
return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
```